# R dataframe: How to split by 2 columns and calculate the mean

Tags: r, dataframe, split, mean

I have a dataframe with several columns like this:

(I have lots of columns from which I want to calculate the mean, so I cannot address them by name)

```
df:
  A    B    C     D     E     F....
  1    1    10    ...   ...   ...
  1    1    30    ...   ...   ...
  1    2    100   ...   ...   ...
  1    2    300   ...   ...   ...
  2    1    4     ...   ...   ...
  2    1    6     ...   ...   ...
  2    1    8     ...   ...   ...
```

Now I want to split this dataFrame into Groups of A and B and calculate the mean like that:

```
A=1:
    B=1: mean = 20
    B=2: mean = 200
A=2:
    B=1: mean = 6
```

How would I do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: With `dplyr` you can `df %>% group_by(A, B) %>% summarise(mean=mean(C))`

Comment: With base `R`,  `aggregate(C ~ A + B, data = df, FUN = mean)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for that.

For

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  gather("Col","Numbers", C:length(.)) %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Numbers))
```

Best,

Colin